# How to display a ForeignKey as RadioSelect options from DetailView in Django?

Tags: django, e-commerce, detailview

I'm learning how to program in python/django and I've challenged myself to build an ecommerce site for a printing business. The general idea follows:

Once the customer chooses a product, he will have to select from a set of options(Size, Frame-Border Width, Material) in order to customize his product. Something worth mentioning is that each option has characteristics that distinguish it from the others. For example: Each size has a width and a height wich are attributes not required for a Material. Then he will upload an image (but I ain't there yet) and the store will process his order.

Therefore, I've chosen to design the models.py as follow (simplified):

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length = 150)
    base_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 12, decimal_places = 2, default=0.00)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = ('Product')
        verbose_name_plural = ('Products')

    #Methods. There is a method for each option.
    def get_materials(self):
        materials = self.materials.all()
        return materials

#There is a model for each option. Each model has a ForeignKey to Product.
class Material(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, verbose_name = "Product", related_name="materials")
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
    code = models.SlugField(max_length=150)
    price_per_meter = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 12, decimal_places = 2, blank = True, default = 0.00)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-created_at"]
        verbose_name_plural = "Materials"
```

To simplify things I'm using DetailView. So in my catalogue.urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.views.generic import DetailView
from catalogue.models import Product

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', DetailView.as_view(
        model = Product,
        template_name = "detail.html"
        )),
)
```

So, here is the question *finally*:

**How can I customize my DetailView so that in the UI each option displays as RadioSelect?**

Similar questions have been posted, but they are more related to forms: i.e. how to display a ForeignKey as a RadioSelect in a form.

My current approach uses the following detail.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<h1>{{ product.title }}</h1>

<h2>Please select one of the following:</h2>
<p>{{ product.get_materials }}</p>
<p>{{ product.get_sizes }}</p>
<p>{{ product.get_border_width }}</p>
<p>{{ product.get_border_color }}</p>

{% endblock %}
```

That renders the following:
*I added some random data to the db*

```
Please select one of the following:

[<Material: Material 1>, <Material: Material 2>]

[<Size: Size 1>, <Size: Size 2>]

[<BorderWidth: Border 1>, <BorderWidth: Border 2>]

[<BorderColor: Color 1>, <BorderColor: Color 1>]
```

Any help/pin-pointing in the right direction will be appreciated.

Comment: You seem to be talking about a form which you think isn't a form.

Comment: You might also find that class-based views are a hard place to start with Django (especially when handling forms). For a non-class-based introduction, see Django's ["Working with forms"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/) guide.

Comment: @slackjake Hmm...perhaps lol. I thought that I couldn't use a form for a product view since a form will post the info to the database (i.e. create a "new product")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, a `DetailView` is for displaying data. Given that you're asking the user questions ("Which materials?", "Which sizes?" *etc.*), you'll almost certainly really *do* want to use forms. This is what forms are designed for!

In order for the following to work, I suggest you reverse how your `ForeignKey`s are defined; I assume you want the same material used in multiple products, not the other way 'round! Add a field like `material = models.ForeignKey(Material, related_name='products')` to your `Product`, and delete the `product` field from `Material` *etc.*

Using forms might end up being pretty easy in your situation. Check out the ["Creating forms from models" documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/modelforms/), and try something like the following:

```
# urls.py
from django.views.generic import CreateView

urlpatterns = patterns('', ...
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', CreateView.as_view(
        model = Product,
        template_name = "add_product.html"
    )),
)
```

This would get you the default `Select` widget -- the "Creating forms from models" documentaiton (above) has information on [customising the widget used to draw form fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-field-types-or-widgets). You would need to create a new form (inheriting from `ModelForm`) and point your view at that form:

```
# forms.py
from django import forms

from catalogue.models import Product

class ProductForm(forms.ModelForms):
    class Meta:
        model = Product 
        widgets = {
            'material': forms.RadioSelect()
            ...
        }

# urls.py

from catalogue.forms import ProductForm

# add the following parameter to your call to as_view():
...
    'form_class': ProductForm
```

Comment: Thanks for such a quick answer! I does seem that I had my logic backwards ^^) Just a simple question: should the form have a "post" method in the "detail.html" template ? Or how would I proceed so that the user doesn't create a new product in the database and rather pass the info to the cart? (of course adding things to the cart is another story, but just want to make sure if I should use "post"? Thanks

Comment: For that you would be wanting to store the information in session/cookie.  You could possibly use CreateView for this but you would need to override form_valid and not sure what else.

Comment: @slackjake Thanks! As I pointed out I'm still in the learning curve. Both yours and @ supervacuo's answers pointed me in the right track which is awesome! Thank you both for your time and prompt response. As a newbie in Stackoverflow I can't upvote, but have my votes in spirt!

Comment: Sorry, keeping the template called `detail.html` was a mistake — I've changed it to `add_product.html` in the example above. On not saving to the database, `slackjake` is right; store in the session instead. You'll indeed want to [override `CreateView.form_valid`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#model-forms), saving the form with `commit=False` and storing the `Product` instance in `self.request.session` instead.